# IsNull ExecuteSql incorrect syntax error

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to solve `'incorrect syntax near ExecuteSql'` error for the following line of code:

```
IsNull (ExecuteSql ('Numeric' , SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables a
INNER JOIN sys.indexes b ON a.object_id = b.object_id WHERE b.is_primary_key = 1 AND a.name = @@ObjectName AND a.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID (@@SchemaName)'), 0)
```

and I'm at a loss.

I think I understand that where it finds a null it will return 0, but beginning the line with IsNull confuses me.

Also, the letters `a` and `b` and `a.object` or `b.object` or `b.is_primary` I don't understand yet.

I don't suppose anyone could walk me through what is happening here.

I cannot even find what @@ refers to.

Comment: This doesn't look to make sense, did you read the MSDN on `IsNull`.  You need `ISNULL(Column, Value)` that is IsNull checks if a column or an aggregate is null or returns null and not an entire `EXECUTESQL` Expression.

Comment: @JonH - My understanding of the ExecuteSQL() function was that it returns the value in the first field of the first row returned by the specified query?  So ISNULL() should work?

Comment: @Dems - That is very true I think after looking at it - I don't use `executesql` very much, that this is doable..meh +1 :).

Comment: Please could the down-voter give a reason so the OP can address it???

Answer (score 2):

ExecuteSQL() takes two parameters, both of which need to be strings.  You don't have an opening `'` for your second string...

Try this, with the missing `'` added back in?  (Note: I didn't check anything else about your query)

```
SELECT
  IsNull(
    ExecuteSql(
     'Numeric',
     'SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables a
      INNER JOIN sys.indexes b ON a.object_id = b.object_id 
      WHERE b.is_primary_key = 1 
      AND a.name = @@ObjectName 
      AND a.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID (@@SchemaName)'
    )
    , 0
  )
```

In terms of the letters, etc, they're standard SQL syntax...

The phrase `sys.tables a` means that you are using the table `sys.tables` but want to alias it to `a` from now on.  That's why you see `a.name` later on.

The same applies to `sys.indexes b`, creating the alias `b` for table `sys.indexes`.

I'd consider this bad-practice in this form.  It's just the same as having variable `a` and `b` in another language.  Much better to have aliases/variable names that *mean* something in my opinion.  But this does server to shorten the code.

For the `@@` sections are system variables explained on the msdn blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlpbm/archive/2008/07/03/executesql.aspx).

```
@@ObjectName - corresponds to the name field in sys.objects.
               The variable will be replaced with the name of the current object.

@@SchemaName - corresponds to the name field in sys.schemas.
               The variable will be replaced with the schema for the current
               object if the current object belongs to a schema.
```

The ExecuteSQL() function then executes the code in the second parameter, but only takes the first value of the first column, and returns it as the type in ExecuteSQL()'s first parameter.  As it always returns one value, it may return NULL.  `ISNULL(ExecuteSQL(), 0)` replaces any NULL return value with a 0.